# Login in to Amazon using BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am working on a script to scrape some information off Amazon's Prime Now grocery website. However, I am stumbling on the first step in which I am attempting to start a session and login to the page.

I am fairly positive that the issue is in building the 'data' object. There are 10 input's in the html but the data object I have constructed only has 9, with the missing one being the submit button. I am not entirely sure if it is relevant as this is my first time working with BeautifulSoup.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! All of my code is below, with the last if/else statement confirming that it has not worked when I run the code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# define URL where login form is located
site = 'https://primenow.amazon.com/ap/signin?clientContext=133-1292951-7489930&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fprimenow.amazon.com%2Fap-post-redirect%3FsiteState%3DclientContext%253D131-7694496-4754740%252CsourceUrl%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fprimenow.amazon.com%25252Fhome%252Csignature%253DIFISh0byLJrJApqlChzLdkc2FCEj3D&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.assoc_handle=amzn_houdini_desktop_us&openid.mode=checkid_setup&marketPlaceId=A1IXFGJ6ITL7J4&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&pageId=amzn_pn_us&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.pape.max_auth_age=3600'

# initiate session
session = requests.Session()

# define session headers
session.headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.61 Safari/537.36',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Referer': site
}

# get login page
resp = session.get(site)
html = resp.text

# get BeautifulSoup object of the html of the login page
soup = BeautifulSoup(html , 'lxml')

# scrape login page to get all the needed inputs required for login
data = {}
form = soup.find('form')
for field in form.find_all('input'):
    try: 
        data[field['name']] = field['value']

    except:
        pass

# add username and password to the data for post request
data['email'] = 'my email'
data['password'] = 'my password'

# submit post request with username / password and other needed info
post_resp = session.post(site, data = data)

post_soup = BeautifulSoup(post_resp.content , 'lxml')

if post_soup.find_all('title')[0].text == 'Your Account':
    print('Login Successfull')
else:
    print('Login Failed')
```